# pdfkit can possible to used image tag?

Tags: html, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I have a question about using pdfkit is capable to attached base64 image in doc.image of PDFkit?
usually in PDFkit doc.image can be attached image/sample.jpeg.

```
doc.image('images/test.jpeg', 320, 145, {width: 200, height: 100})
   .text('Stretch', 320, 130);
```

is that possible to attached base64 image in PDFkit instead of file image like this:

```
 doc.image('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...', 320, 145, {width: 200, height: 100})
       .text('Stretch', 320, 130);
```

the image will display in generated pdf?

Thanks for the answer